# mount: Operation not permitted

Tags: mount

I have an ext4 filesystem image named `linux-partition-image` that I want to get data off of, and executing the command

```
mount ./linux-partition-image mountdir -o ro,loop
```

as root results in the message `mount: mountdir: mount failed: Operation not permitted.` The same message shows up if I give the command a directory that doesn't exist, so the error must be happening before the mount operation itself.

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407

Comment: Well, turns out the kernel couldn't create a loop device. Rebooting allowed it to do so and mount the image.

Answer (score 1):

I get that as well, and there is no need to reboot the machine to mount the image.

Simply issue

`modprobe loop`

and I can do `mount -o loop` afterwards.